# See the distribution of secondary requests grouped by time interval in sql

Tags: sql, grouping, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
RequestId,Type, Date,        ParentRequestId
1         1     2020-10-15    null 
2         2     2020-10-19    1 
3         1     2020-10-20    null 
4         2     2020-11-15    3
```

For this example I am interested in the request type 1 and 2, to make the example simpler. My task is to query a big database and to see the distribution of the secondary transaction based on the difference of dates with the parent one. So the result would look like:

```
Interval,Percentage
0-7 days,50 %
8-15 days,0 %
16-50 days, 50 %
```

So for the first line from teh expected result we have the request with the id 2 and for the third line from the expected result we have the request with the id 4 because the date difference fits in this interval.

How to achieve this?

I'm using sql server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We like to see your attempts, but by the looks of it, it seems like you're going to need to treat this table as 2 tables and do a basic GROUP BY, but make it *fancy* by grouping on a CASE statement.

```sql
WITH dateDiffs as (
    /* perform our date calculations first, to get that out of the way */
    SELECT 
      DATEDIFF(Day, parent.[Date], child.[Date]) as daysDiff,
      1 as rowsFound
    FROM    (SELECT RequestID, [Date] FROM myTable WHERE Type = 1) parent
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT ParentRequestID, [Date] FROM myTable WHERE Type = 2) child
    ON parent.requestID = child.parentRequestID
)

/* Now group and aggregate and enjoy your maths! */
SELECT 
  case when daysDiff between 0 and 7 then '0-7'
       when daysDiff between 8 and 15 then '8-15'
       when daysDiff between 16 and 50 THEN '16-50'
       else '50+' 
   end as myInterval,
   sum(rowsFound) as totalFound,
   (select sum(rowsFound) from dateDiffs) as totalRows,
   1.0 * sum(rowsFound) / (select sum(rowsFound) from dateDiffs) * 100.00 as percentFound
FROM dateDiffs
GROUP BY 
   case when daysDiff between 0 and 7 then '0-7'
       when daysDiff between 8 and 15 then '8-15'
       when daysDiff between 16 and 50 THEN '16-50'
       else '50+' 
   end;
```

Comment: It works like a charm. I would have put some minimal code, but I didn't knew from where to start... Thank you.

Comment: @BudaGavril . . . This seems way more complicated than necessary.  In addition, I don't think it returns rows with zero values, as you specify in the question.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like basically a `join` and `group by` query:

```
with dates as (
      select 0 as lo, 7 as hi, '0-7 days' as grp union all
      select 8 as lo, 15 as hi, '8-15 days' union all
      select 16 as lo, 50 as hi, '16-50 days'
     )      
select d.grp,
       count(*) as cnt,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as raio
from dates left join
     (t join
      t tp
      on tp.RequestId = t. ParentRequestId
     )
     on datediff(day, tp.date, t.date) between d.lo and d.hi
group by d.grp
order by d.lo;
```

The only trick is generating all the date groups, so you have rows with zero values.

Comment: While I appreciate how much easier this is to read, I'm getting a ratio miscalculation with this, and it's taking longer to run for some reason (then again, a tiny sample on sqlfiddle is kinda a bad sample). You have me on the missing zero rows, however. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c70c6/5)

Comment: It doesn’t give the correct ratios. Your answer gave them all 33% in the fiddle I tried it in because you’re counting all the dates left joined to the actual data. See fiddle linked in earlier comment.